# Getting people name and number from mobile contact in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I want exactly this process in my app https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKCXwm7r838. But the code in this tutorial is for older IOS version, i'm using IOS 10, Xcode 8.2, Swift 3.0, So its not working for me. I tried the following code to display the contact list. It works.

```
import UIKit
import ContactsUI
class ViewController: UIViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
    func addExistingContact()
    {

    }
    func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contacts: CNContact)
    {
       // print(contacts.givenName)

    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
        contactPicker.delegate = self
        contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys =
            [CNContactGivenNameKey
                , CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
        self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func contactPickerDidCancel(picker: CNContactPickerViewController)
    {
        print("Cancel Contact Picker")
    }
}
```

Now, what I want is, when I select any contact name from the list, the contact list must disappear immediately, and then the selected name and number must be displayed in two labels/textFields in a viewController. Can someone tell me what code should i use ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace methods `contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contacts: CNContact)` and `contactPickerDidCancel(picker: CNContactPickerViewController)` with

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, 
              didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {

}

func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
     // You can fetch selected name and number in the following way

    // user name
    let userName:String = contact.givenName 

    // user phone number
    let userPhoneNumbers:[CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>] = contact.phoneNumbers        
    let firstPhoneNumber:CNPhoneNumber = userPhoneNumbers[0].value 

    // user phone number string
    let primaryPhoneNumberStr:String = firstPhoneNumber.stringValue 
}

func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {

}
```

Given that your requirement is for the ContactPicker to close immediately after clicking on contact, you **shouldn't** implement the following methods. **Remove the below given methods from your code**.

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {

}

func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContactProperties contactProperties: [CNContactProperty]) {

}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what code should i use inside these methods to close the contact list immediately when i click any contact name. And that selected name and number must be printed.

Comment: @Tester, I believe that my current edited answer resolves the problem. Please let me know if I missed something

Answer (score 1):

I will tell you how to get your contact list. The last part of your post (The list stuff) you will have to do it yourself, as it's just playing around with TableView controllers.
First import:

```
import Contacts
```

I use this, for example, to get all my contacts:

```
   let store = CNContactStore()
        var contacts = [CNContact]()
        let keys = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName), CNContactSocialProfilesKey] as [Any]
        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as! [CNKeyDescriptor])


        do{
            try store.enumerateContacts(with: request){
                (contact, stop) in
                  contacts.append(contact)
            }

            guard contacts.count > 0 else{
                //Show contact list
                return
            }
        } catch let err{
            print(err)
        }
```

Also, somewhere in your code, you will want to ask for Contact Permission:

```
switch CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts){
                        case .authorized:
                             //
                        case .notDetermined:
                            store.requestAccess(for: .contacts){succeeded, err in
                                guard err == nil && succeeded else{
                                    return
                                }
                            }
                        case .denied:
                            //
                        case .restricted:
                            //
                        default:
                            print("Not handled")
                    }
```

**IMPORTANT:** Add in your info.plist:

```
Privacy - Contacts Usage Description
```

Comment: I got my contact list dude, using the code in the post. I want to select only one contact name. And that selected contact name and number must be printed, at the same time the contact list must  get disappeared.